# Unknown commands hogging all my cpu. " ./10 -c/tmp/ ..."

Tags: linux, command-line, process, htop

What command is `./10 -c/tmp/ ...` ?
<strike>I have tried killing it with no luck. Other than reboot what are my options?</strike>

How could I find out what triggered it? What command was it, I need to identify what happened on the development server.

It was eating up all my ram and virtual cores on the VPS.

[image: htop]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not kill it *yet* – you need to have it running in order to be able to investigate it.

In htop, green means it's a thread belonging to some other process. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to collapse threads and show only the main process. Killing a thread is useless because the process will probably just restart it; you need to kill the process (main thread).

Note that the `/tmp/...` does not mean the command was truncated – it's *literally* a file named `...` in the /tmp directory, one of the more common ways for malware to disguise its files.

With the PID of the process, use `ls -l /proc/<pid>/{exe,cwd,root}` to see where it's running from (the executable and the root directory). More hints might be found in `/proc/<pid>/fd/`.

Also use `cat /proc/<pid>/cgroup` or `systemctl status -n0 <pid>` to correlate it to a specific systemd service – e.g. if it shows apache.service then it got in through your webapps. (If you get the result that it belongs to a LXD container – enter the container and repeat the same checks inside the container.) You can also run `systemd-cgls` to get a complete list of processes by cgroup.

If the system has the kernel auditing facility available, use `auditctl -w /tmp/... -p wa` to have it log any future process that attempts to modify that file (or `-p rwa` to also detect reads).

Comment: Oh man, I panicked and had to killed the top main process. The dev server was stalled. I will do what you suggested it I see it again.

Comment: It was docker container the postgres db was at 99.9 and all the RAM used up. I am currently watching for it.